# Upgrade Expo CLI have unknown error --assetPlugins

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I upgrade to latest Expo CLI 2.19.2 and tried upgrade my expo application using SDK 33.

When I called expo start, i have a message saying:

> Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable) error: unknown option `--assetPlugins'
>
> Metro Bundler process exited with code 1 Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your
>   env to view the stack trace.

I tried to set EXPO_DEBUG=true on Mac but doesn't show any debugging details when running expo start again.

I found it i should called export EXPO_DEBUG=true

Here is additional message:

> error: unknown option `--assetPlugins'
>
> Metro Bundler process exited with code 1 Error: Metro Bundler process
>   exited with code 1
>       at ChildProcess. (/@expo/xdl@54.1.2/src/Project.js:1598:16)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/simonlam/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Project.js:2347:191)
>       at /Users/simonlam/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Project.js:2347:437
>       at new Promise ()
>       at ChildProcess. (/Users/simonlam/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Project.js:2347:99)
>       at ChildProcess.packagerProcess.once (/@expo/xdl@54.1.2/src/Project.js:1595:5)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:276:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)

Answer (score 21):

Be sure to also upgrade "react-native" to version 33.

```
yarn add react-native@https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz
```

Also check "jest-expo" has been updated and you change the "sdkVersion" in app.json to match SDK 33.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is about version mismatch in `package.json` and `app.json` in your expo project. You need to perform upgrades as given below,

1. Update your Expo SDK Version

   Open the `app.json` file from the project and change `sdkVersion` to 33.0.0
2. Update your Dependancies

   Open the `package.json` file and update the following dependencies,

   - Update the `jest-expo` to ^33.0.0 in `devDependencies`
   - Update the `react-native` to ^0.59.10 in `dependencies`
   - Update the `expo` to ^33.0.0 in `dependencies`
   - Update the `react` to ^16.8.3 in `dependencies`

After making the changes, run `npm install` and then start the project by clearing the older js build cache by running `expo r -c` and you will be good to go. The `Metro Bundler` will crash only if you have SDK version mismatch. For more information, you can read through [Upgrading the Expo SDK Step by Step](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this a couple times and it always feels a little mysterious. From my experience it's either a package mismatch or you need to clear the expo cache.

Triple check you have the right versions in your `package.json`. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/#sdk-33

Delete any expo related folders and start expo with a cleared cache

`rm -rf node_modules/* && npm i && expo start -c`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this issue generally arises due to mismatch of package versions of sdk, expo, expo-cli so make sure all are compatible.

In my case the issue was the expo-cli version was old and sdk was latest (38 as available today) and the upgrade of expo-cli was failing.

The error looked like -

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                          │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.11.2).                                                                                 │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.11.0                                                                                                │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice; for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version   │
│                                                                                                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This is what I did to make it work -

```
  which expo-cli
  rm -rf <path>
  npm install -g expo-cli # This ensures you have latest expo cli
```

Now to run

```
  expo-cli start
```